# Pipe operator behaviour

Tags: elixir

According to [Elixir Tutorial on Enumerables and Streams](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html):

> The |> symbol is the pipe operator: it simply takes the output from the expression on its left side and passes it as the input to the function call on its right side.
>
> All the functions in the Enum module are eager.

So what is the difference in following statements? Why does the last one return a different result?

```
iex(1)> 1..1_000 |> Enum.reverse |> Enum.take 5
[1000, 999, 998, 997, 996]

iex(2)> (Enum.reverse 1..1_000) |> Enum.take 5
[1000, 999, 998, 997, 996]

iex(3)> Enum.reverse 1..1_0000 |> Enum.take 5
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Arguments for methods before a pipe operator should be in parenthesis.

All of these are equivalent:

```
1..1_000 |> Enum.reverse |> Enum.take 5
#=> [1000, 999, 998, 997, 996]

(Enum.reverse 1..1_000) |> Enum.take 5
#=> [1000, 999, 998, 997, 996]

Enum.reverse(1..1_000) |> Enum.take 5
#=> [1000, 999, 998, 997, 996]
```

***Except* this one:**

```
Enum.reverse 1..1_0000 |> Enum.take 5
#=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Here, Elixir first calculates the `Enum.take/2` method with **1..1_0000** and **5** as arguments and then calls `Enum.reverse/1` on the result.

```
# It is actually equal to this:
Enum.reverse(1..1_0000 |> Enum.take 5)

# or this if you simplify it:
Enum.reverse(Enum.take(1..1_0000, 5)
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot about operator precedence http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#|%3E/2